# How much damage does a damage+ tag add?

Tags: blacklight-retribution

When equipping a damage + tag (such as the Orange Portal Gun), how much extra damage are we talking per shot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each gun/receiver actually receives a different level of stat boost based on the part/tag. For LMGs, the +damage tag gives +1, and for BARs, the +damage tag gives +2. Damage is capped per receiver, also, so if you've got a BAR that already is doing 200 damage, the +damage tag won't add anything as 200 is the BAR's cap.

Damage uses integer math, so a tag won't add '.75' damage or anything: if the stats on your loadout don't change, then the tag just isn't adding anything at all.

Answer (score 1):

When I look on the stats on the Orange Portal Gun, I can not see any change in damage, leading me to think it is because the damage increase is less then 1, since when you're changing other parts on a gun you can see how much increase/decrease to damage in whole numbers the change will give without decimals.

I'm new to Blacklight so it is quite possible I'm wrong about it, but the stat changes on the tags are really small.

Comment: Yeah...that's what I figured. On the other hand, when you equip something like the 8-ball which gives you increased accuracy (if I remember correctly), you can see it change because accuracy is measured with decimals........

Comment: @elegantonyx Exactly, I just bought a tacticle smg that has 30 base damage where the Orange Portal Gun will increase the damage by 1 so if you have a weapon with higher like the default the damage increase is going to be so small it wont show on the chart